# Equivalent of %g in java.text.DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, floating-point, formatting

I'm using FreeMarker which uses [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for its numeric formatting. I'm used to `sprintf()`-style formatting, and a lot of times I use [`%g`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type) which chooses the shorter of `%f` or `%e` formatting.

Is there any way to get an equivalent using `java.text.DecimalFormat`?

Answer (score 1):

The straight-up answer to your question is probably not. Not without formatting it in both formats and comparing their length by hand and outputting the one you like better.

Is there any possibility you could use a [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) instead? Then you get `%g` and all the `sprintf()` formats.